# Appcelerator Studio app not running in device

Tags: java, android, titanium, appcelerator

I am using titanium sdk version `5.0.2`, I am trying to run the app on my android device, it throws the following error

```
[INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: cmd /s /c C:\Users\USER_NAME\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy compile C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\ac (1)\Academic Communicators\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test,target=device --no-colors
'C:\Users\USER_NAME\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\alloy\bin\alloy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Running `ti build --platform android` in terminal shows

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.4, Titanium SDK version 5.0.2.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

[ERROR] JDK (Java Development Kit) not found.
[ERROR] If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly set.
[ERROR] The JDK can be downloaded and installed from http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

I tried replacing the `alloy` file in project, also set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;` ,nothing works! Help me finding the solution.

Thanks

**Edit**

javac version is `javac 1.7.0_80` and
`ti info` shows jdk issue

```
Java Development Kit Issues

  x  JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.
     If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly
     set.
     The JDK is required for must be manually downloaded and installed from
     http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run `ti info` to see what is missing. Also check your PATH variable. You said you set JAVA_HOME so you should be able to run "javac --version" from a terminal. If that is not working please add the path to PATH.

Comment: just to make sure: you followed: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Oracle_JDK ? 32bit version?